# How can you tell whether a disk is spinning (without sound/touch)?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

Is there a "programmatic" way to determine whether a disk is spinning or not (spinning, not necessarily reading/writing)?

Comment: It's always spinning unless it's sleeping. Check if the drive is sleeping perhaps?

Comment: I don't see anything in the SMART attributes.  There may be a way, but it would depend on the specific drive and controller.  You would have to read the specifications to find out if it is possible.  I seem to remember some old drives that had a bit that would be on for spinning.

Answer (score 0):

Whether a disk is spinning depends on its power mode; typically the spindle motor will be running in “Active” and “Idle” modes, and stopped in “Standby” and “Sleep” modes. (It gets a bit more complicated with drives with NV cache power management, which I don’t know enough about to cover here.)

If a drive is asleep it’s definitely not spinning (or doing anything else, including communicating with the host); otherwise you can interrogate it about its current mode.

For an ATA drive, the “Check Power Mode” command will do this. Send the value `E5` in the command register, and it will return `FF` in the sector count register if the drive is active or idle.

Doing that programatically is venturing into Stack Overflow territory, but here’s a snippet of C that will do it on Windows:

```c
int isSpinning = -1;
HANDLE hDevice = CreateFile(TEXT("\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0"), GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
if (hDevice != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    DWORD cb = 0;
    ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX cmd = {sizeof(ATA_PASS_THROUGH_EX)};
    cmd.AtaFlags = ATA_FLAGS_DRDY_REQUIRED; /*  Require drive to be ready  */
    cmd.TimeOutValue = 3;                   /*  Arbitrary timeout (seconds)  */
    cmd.CurrentTaskFile[6] = 0xE5;          /*  "Check Power Mode" in command register  */
    if (DeviceIoControl(hDevice, IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH, &cmd, sizeof(cmd), &cmd, sizeof(cmd), &cb, 0))
    {
        /*  FF in sector count register means the drive is 
            active or idle (and therefore spinning)  */
        isSpinning = cmd.CurrentTaskFile[1] == 0xFF;
    }
}
```